# Prime numbers of certain form

Tags: prime-numbers

Are there infinitely many prime numbers of the form $p^{2h}+p^h+1$, where $p$ is a prime and $h$ is a positive integer?

Comment: Already $p^2+p+1$ should be prime for infinite many primes $p$ , although we cannot prove it. The same for $p^6+p^3+1$

Comment: Aren’t they divisible by $3$ if $p\ne3$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Not if $p \equiv 2 \mod 3$.

Comment: For primes $p$ such that $p^2+p+1$ is prime, see [OEIS sequence A053182](https://oeis.org/A053182).  For primes $p$ such that $p^6+p^3+1$ is prime, see [A066100](https://oeis.org/A066100).

Comment: Despite the evidence for infinite many such primes , it is probably out of reach to prove it.

Comment: @RobertIsrael:  you’re right, and if $h\not\equiv0\pmod3$

Comment: Indeed, there are no integer polynomials of degree $>1$ that have been proven to generate infinitely many primes.

Comment: @RobertIsrael OP didn't say they are generated by the *same* polynomial

Comment: @Raffaele Actually,  $p^{2h}+p^h+1 = x^2 + x + 1$ where $x = p^h$, so if the answer to OP's question is yes, there are infinitely many primes generated by the polynomial $x^2+x+1$ for integer $x$.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner No, you mean $h \not\equiv 0 \pmod 2$.  Which is a good thing, since as shown in my answer $h$ must be a power of $3$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael:  you’re right again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [generalized Bunyakovsky conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture#Generalized_Bunyakovsky_conjecture) implies that there are, as long as $x^{2h} + x^h + 1$ is irreducible (which I think is true if and only if $h$ is a power of $3$).

EDIT: Yes, that is the case.  $x^{2h}+x^h+1 = \dfrac{x^{3h}-1}{x^h - 1}$ is the product of the cyclotomic polynomials $C_d(x)$ where $d$ divides $3h$ but not $h$.  If $h$ is a power of $3$, the only such $d$ is $3h$ itself: $x^{2h} + x^h + 1 = C_{3h}(x)$ is irreducible.  If $h$ is divisible by some prime $q \ne 3$, then $d = 3h/q$ is another $d$, and $x^{2h}+x^h+1$ is reducible.

Comment: The criterion holds at least upto $h=729$